# Escape single quote in select statement -- IN clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

u    I want to get the string 'Username,Surname,Name' like this 
    'Username','Surname','Name'

I try this

```
   DECLARE @Header varchar(MAX)
SELECT @Header= 'Username,Surname,Name'  

SELECT @Header =  replace(@Header,',',''',''')
SELECT @Header = ''+@Header+''

SELECT * from myTable where field in ($header)
```

The result should be like this  'Username','Surname','Name'

but I don't know why it display nothing 
sorry for my bad english .

Comment: @M.Ali

I try this SELECT * from myTable where field in ('Username','Surname','Name') work fine 
but this I try this SELECT * from myTable where field in ('Username,Surname,Name') NO !!!!!
I'm in SQL SERVER 2005

Comment: Sorry my mistake I got it mixed up with SSRS query designer :S

Comment: No problem :) tnx any way

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
DECLARE @Header varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @sqlstmt varchar(MAX)
SET @Header= 'Username,Surname,Name'  

SET @Header =  replace(@Header,',',''',''')
SET @Header = ''''+@Header+''''

SET @sqlstmt = 'SELECT * from myTable where field in ('+@header+')'
exec (@sqlstmt)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147315).

Is there any reason why you couldn't just use something like the following?

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE field IN ( '''Username''', '''Surname''', '''Name''' );
```

That would return all columns for any rows in `myTable` where the value of `field` is one of:

- `'Username'`
- `'Surname'`
- `'Name'`

Note that, to escape a single quote in a string literal, just use `''`. So a literal containing a single single quote would be `''''`.